# Why can't the limit for core file size be increased after first set in bash? (ulimit: core file size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted)

Tags: linux, bash, dump

While trying to obtain the core file from a program that exits with segmentation fault, I discovered that I need to set the core file size with ulimit command (the value is set to 0 by default).

Those are the default values (when I first open a bash terminal).

```
**core file size          (blocks, -c) 0**
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31146
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31146
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

After I first set this limit, I can set it to a lower limit anytime but I can never set a higher limit than it already is. I have to close the bash and open it again. What is the reason for it?

```
user@PC:~$ ulimit -c 10

user@PC:~$ ulimit -c
10

user@PC:~$ ulimit -c 11
**bash: ulimit: core file size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted**

user@PC:~$ ulimit -c
10

user@PC:~$ ulimit -c
9
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot increase the core file size limit, since you are not running as root.

Linux allows everybody to reduce the limit, but increasing can only be done by root.

This is a little gotcha : The first ulimit sets the value without the need to be
root, but then increasing it fails because you are not root.